# Jquery animate function does not for both selected seletor

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('#home-logo').aniAutoHeight(aniHeightSpeed).animate({ backgroundColor: '#004329', color: 'gray', paddingTop: 50 }, aniHeightSpeed, function(e) {
    if ($(document).height() > ($('#home-copy').offset().top + $('#home-copy').outerHeight())) {
        $('#home-copy').height($(document).height() - $('#home-copy').offset().top);
    }
});

$('#home-copy').aniAutoHeight(aniHeightSpeed).animate({ backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'gray', paddingTop: 50 }, aniHeightSpeed, function(e) {
    if ($(document).height() > ($('#home-copy').offset().top + $('#home-copy').outerHeight())) {
        $('#home-copy').height($(document).height() - $('#home-copy').offset().top);
    }
});
```

above code is about changing height of content boxes 
I want the height of `'#home-logo'` is the same as `#home-copy`, but it seems does not work at all. `#hoe-logo` does not go the way down

anyone know how to fix it? thank you very much

Comment: Could you share your HTML?

Comment: http://50.62.140.177/foxcode/index.html